# The conflict is caused by: The user requested urllib3==1.26 requests 2.23.0 depends on urllib3!=1.25.0, !=1.25.1, <1.26 and >=1.21.1

Tags: python, pip, urllib

I am trying to install a library packages mentioned in **requirements.txt**

Here's the error I got:

```
PS C:\Users\lalit\Downloads\The-Movie-Cinema-master> pip install -r requirements.txt
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Collecting Flask==1.1.1
  Using cached Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting gunicorn==19.9.0
  Using cached gunicorn-19.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
Collecting Jinja2==2.11.3
  Using cached Jinja2-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe==1.1.1
  Using cached MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Werkzeug==0.15.5
  Using cached Werkzeug-0.15.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (328 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.2 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.21.2)
Collecting scipy>=0.15.1
  Using cached scipy-1.7.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (33.8 MB)
Collecting nltk==3.5
  Using cached nltk-3.5.zip (1.4 MB)
Collecting scikit-learn>=0.18
  Using cached scikit_learn-0.24.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (6.9 MB)
Collecting pandas>=0.19
  Using cached pandas-1.3.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (10.2 MB)
Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
Collecting jsonschema==3.2.0
  Using cached jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting tmdbv3api==1.6.1
  Using cached tmdbv3api-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting lxml==4.6.3
  Using cached lxml-4.6.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (3.5 MB)
Collecting urllib3==1.26
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (136 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 136 kB 6.4 MB/s
Collecting requests==2.23.0
  Using cached requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting pickleshare==0.7.5
  Using cached pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
Collecting click>=5.1
  Using cached click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24
  Using cached itsdangerous-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting joblib
  Using cached joblib-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (303 kB)
Collecting regex
  Using cached regex-2021.8.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (270 kB)
Collecting tqdm
  Using cached tqdm-4.62.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Collecting soupsieve>1.2
  Using cached soupsieve-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Collecting pyrsistent>=0.14.0
  Using cached pyrsistent-0.18.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (62 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema==3.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 12)) (56.0.0)
Collecting attrs>=17.4.0
  Using cached attrs-21.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema==3.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 12)) (1.16.0)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of urllib3 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of lxml to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of tmdbv3api to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jsonschema to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of beautifulsoup4 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of nltk to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of werkzeug to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of markupsafe to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jinja2 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of gunicorn to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of flask to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 16) and urllib3==1.26 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested urllib3==1.26
    requests 2.23.0 depends on urllib3!=1.25.0, !=1.25.1, <1.26 and >=1.21.1

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
PS C:\Users\lalit\Downloads\The-Movie-Cinema-master>
```

The command to install the packages: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

After then I ran into the error. How to solve these issues step by step?

Answer (score 5):

make sure use latest versions :

for me fix was using below latest versions

```
requests==2.28.1 (https://pypi.org/project/requests/)
urllib3==1.26.12 (https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do what the error message is saying.

> To fix this you could try to:
>
> 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
> 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

Change the requirements to loosen the package versions or just remove the version for `urllib` and let pip figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, I did that too I changed the version and removed it but still the issue not getting solved, still throwing the same error.                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                     
`WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\jsonschema.exe' ->`

Comment: That's actually a different error, I found a Github issue [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9023). Based on what I read, try running it in administrator mode, see if that works.